# \thefield, entrykey an \xifinlist

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox

I try to use `\thefield` in combination with `\xifinlist`. That works for all field, except for `entrykey`.

See this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{CPG,
    title={CPG},

}
\end{filecontents}
\listadd{\toto}{CPG}
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{
  \xifinlist{\thefield{entrykey}}{\toto}{oui}{non}

  \xifinlist{\thefield{title}}{\toto}{oui}{non}
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{CPG}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I expected the first test would result "oui", but it results "non".

Any idea?

Comment: I think this is an expansion issue

Comment: that seems to be related to the \detokenize on l. 6632 of biblatex.sty

Comment: \listeadd{\toto}{\detokenize{CPG}} solve this issue…

Comment: Well, this is your answer then ;-)

Comment: yes, I added it just now. I was waiting for more test to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that biblatex detokenize the entrykey field.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{CPG,
    title={CPG},

}
\end{filecontents}
\listeadd{\toto}{\detokenize{CPG}}
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{
  \xifinlist{\thefield{entrykey}}{\toto}{oui}{non}

  \xifinlist{\thefield{title}}{\toto}{oui}{non}
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{CPG}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Solve my issue.